# Degree of maneuverability mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics

According to the traditional kinematic theory for mobile robots [1][2] a mobile robot with a steerable wheel and two passive casters presents a $\delta_m=2,\delta_s=1,\delta_M=3$. This is easy to explain, looking at the kinematic constraints imposed by the standard wheel. What I cannot understand is the interpretation of these numbers, normally a degree of maneuverability $\delta_M=3$ would imply that the robot is able to place the ICR at any point of the plane. What only would be possible if the caster wheels are also active (motorized). In the case that the caster wheels are passive, the robot would be able to move in any direction but cannot change its orientation what actually would imply for me having a $\delta_M=2$ as the synchrodrive do.

Am I interpreting something wrong? There should be something else to consider, in terms of actuation etc 
to calculate or interpret these coefficients?

[1] Campion G, Bastin G, D'Andrea-Novel B (Hrsg) (1993) Structural properties and classification of kinematic and dynamic models of wheeled mobile robots
[2] Siegwart R, Nourbakhsh IR (2004) Introduction to autonomous mobile robots